# Silverlight LOB app w/ WCF RIA Services on IIS Web farm with ARR for redundancy - suggestions to handle state

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm wondering if anyone has some experience with this.
My concern is with session state. To simplify the issue, we would like to develop services to be stateless, and keep all state on client, in Silverlight frontend. 
Is WCF RIA using state? what could be the best approach for this?

Any suggestions on keeping all state on client? Can I use ASP.NET membership authentication with such approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not a safe way to use session in the client (if possible at all). I guess you want to accomplish session state distribution across multiple servers. You can store sessions in [SQL Server](http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx) instead of memory.
You can use ASP.NET membership provider or write your own in pair with WCF RIA, no problem here.

Comment: Hi. I don't mean to keep the session (in the ASP.NET "session" meaning) at the client, but store all my variables only in client, since silverlight being client technology, have its own memory space on client side. I'm wondering if it's possible to use such approach with and still benefit of asp.net membership authentication . Tnx